# Is using the "IP Security Policies on Active Directory" settings in Group Policy a best practice?

Tags: windows, group-policy, ipsec

Is using the "IP Security Policies on Active Directory" settings in Group Policy a best practice?

I recently created a new GPO and assigned the "Server (Request Security)" policy.
Almost instantly I saw SAs begin to show up on my file server.
This seems too easy, to not use it.

Are there any real downsides to this?

Does everyone already do this, and I just never got that memo?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, no downside other than non windows systems may have network latency while trying to negotiate. You will see slightly higher cpu utilization. It's been a suggestion for ages to use IPsec in require mode, but hardly anyone does it usually because they have non windows systems that make enabling IPsec the equivalent of drinking a cup of hot tea, while having a root canal.  In an all windows environment (or even mostly windows) Kerberos + cert based IPsec (for non windows systems)in require mode allows for fantastic data loss and intrusion protection.  You can couple this (after the domain is secured) to also limit access at the network level.

Comment: Just want to comment setting this up on most modern Linux distros is not that difficult assuming the you're already using an enterprise CA as part of your builds.

Comment: You should not need a CA to use IPsec, unless you are stuck with Linux in your environment.  To presume that an enterprise PKI setup is trivial is very unrealistic.